Can I buy an ETF directrly from BlackRock? How do more ETFs and leave circulation?
TASE is a small stock exchange, and sometimes it takes a long time to do a deal.
BlackRock has ETFs it also sells in TASE, and for tax reasons I need to buy them from there.
So Im wondering if there is some way to buy them directrly from BlackRock?
Theoretically they could use this money to buy more stocks according to the index, and thus keep the value steady.
Additionaly it would be nice to be able to sell it to them later, so i'll know that the traffic in TASE will not hinder me if I ever want to sell.

ETF, probably not. Traditional mutual fund, maybe; ask Black Rock if they have a "house broker"... But since I don't understand your tax issue. I have no idea whether that would do what you need

Sounds like you are worried about ETF premium/discount ratio to NAV, i.e. when the price of an ETF deviates away from the net asset value (how much the stuff it holds is worth) in either direction. A legitimate concern when the liquidity is low.
To your questions,

You can't buy/sell ETF directly from/to ETF issuers (e.g. BlackRock). It's always traded in secondary market. Nor should it matter as long as you get a good price - "good" as in the price reflecting the underlying asset's worth.

ETF generally has low premium/discount ratio to NAV thanks to ETF arbitrage mechanism, which is also how ETF shares join and leave circulation.


Re: #2, ETF issuers enlist the help of so-called authorized participants (AP) to ensure ETF price tracks NAV. If ETF price is much lower than NAV, AP steps in and buys ETF at discount, redeems them with issuer for the underlying assets, sells them for a profit, thereby lifting the ETF price and suppressing the NAV and closing the gap between the two. In this process the shares of ETF AP sent for exchange is also removed from market. This works in the opposite direction when ETF trades at premium (AP buy assets, exchange for newly created shares of ETF and sell them in market for profit.)
This of course is a very high-level description. BlackRock has a nice page on this topic.
https://www.blackrock.com/au/intermediaries/ishares/authorized-participants-and-market-makers
Regarding your trade, it's still important to verify the market conditions by checking the premium/discount ratio, since despite the above mechanism, high P/D ratio is possible when market is stressed. ETF issuers would publish P/D ratio on their websites so make sure to check that.

'ETF' literally means 'Exchange Traded Fonds', and you can only get them there.
Vanguard explains on their website that 'unless you are investing 100 million$+, you can only buy them there'; BlackRock will be no different. The whole reason for existence of ETFs is that they do not have the overhead of handling 'small' buying and selling.
